# Previously working 2TB SSD on USB enclosure suddenly needs initialization. What to do?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

I have the 2TB version of this Asgard AN3+ SSD and it is barely a month old with less than one write cycle on the drive:

https://asgardmemory.com/product/asgard-1tb-an3-nvme-m-2-internal-3600mb-s-ssd-metalic-red/

It's in a working Ugreen USB-C enclosure:

https://www.ugreen.com/products/enclosure-for-m-2-pci-e-nvme-ssd

The drive has 1.5TB of photos and videos on it. I was midway through copying files from a memory card to the drive when things suddenly stopped responding.

- In Windows Disk Management it now says I need to initialize the disk with either MBR or GPT.
- It shows the disk as Not Initialized and the 2TB of space as Unallocated.
- I've tried the disk on a second Ugreen enclosure and it does the same thing.

---

- Why would this suddenly happen?
- Should I initialize with MBR or GPT?
- What are the steps I should do to safely recover all of my data? Do I need to buy a second 2TB+ drive first to recover to? Or is there a way for me to initialize the drive and have it go back to being totally normal with all my files?
- Is this AN3+ drive defective then?

Comment: “Why would this suddenly happen?” - Your partition table has been lost.  If you initialize the drive your files on the drive will be lost.  Why it happened cannot be determined from the information you provided

Comment: The partition table is just a map of the data that's on the drive, right? I don't understand how losing the map would cause the actual 1.5TB of files on the drive to also be lost. The physical NAND memory still contains the data - it's not like all the bits have been overwritten with 0's. As an analogy, if you lose a map for a city, the actual city doesn't disappear...

Comment: I actually indicated the data would be lost if you initialized the drive.  The partition table being lost is the reason Windows is prompting to initialize the drive.  There is a small chance that TestDisk **might** recover the partition table.

Comment: I haven't initialized the drive. I did a Quick Search using TestDisk and it didn't find any partitions. It was able to correctly identify the size of the drive though. Again, I don't understand why losing just the partition table would destroy all my data - If you have a book and rip out just the table of contents, you still have the main contents of the book. My data is still physically there on the SSD, right? It hasn't been overwritten or anything.

Comment: If your data is valuable and not backed up, take it to a recovery expert. If its not that valuable, you may want to run Photorec and see what it recovers. Hopefully it will recover at least some photos (but it don't give you names or directory structures) which will at least show if the data is still on the drive - although if testdisk does not find the partitions, getting better result then photorec is going to be a long shot (at your level of expertise).

Comment: Before trying to create a new partition, do a full bitcopy of the drive so you can have additional bytes at the cherry if what you attempt compounds the problem.